# Searching yahoo programmatically

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I am scraping `yahoo` search results but I get `502 => Net::HTTPBadGateway`. What exactly is causing error? Does that mean `yahoo` detected my bot and banned my ip?

Comment: what do you see when you make that request in your browser?

Comment: why Yahoo? better start off with Google

Answer (score 0):

print the Response object to your console (i recommend awesome_print for this),

but .... its totally routine for search engines to packet shape, throttle or block crawlers. I don't know if yahoo do it, but google certainly do

you could consider http://commoncrawl.org instead

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are blocking your bot, all the big search engines have defences in place to prevent scraping of results pages. However Google and Bing both provide a free search API that you could use to feed your bot.